# xquery for loop and if condition and should only return the first value

Tags: arrays, for-loop, if-statement, xslt, xquery

I am trying to write an xquery which has if inside a for loop.
Below is my request

```
<PersonIdentifiers> 
<PIR  PersonID="1834040001" IDType="N/A" IDNumber="NA" PrimaryID="true" Version="2" IdentiferFormat=""/> 
<PIR  PersonID="111111111" IDType="WEB" IDNumber="abc" PrimaryID="false" Version="3" IdentiferFormat=""/> 
<PIR  PersonID="222222222" IDType="N/A" IDNumber="xyz" PrimaryID="false" Version="4" IdentiferFormat=""/> 
<PIR  PersonID="333333333" IDType="WEB" IDNumber="aaaaaa" PrimaryID="false" Version="5" IdentiferFormat=""/> 
 <PIR  PersonID="444444444" IDType="WEB" IDNumber="aaaaaa" PrimaryID="false" Version="6" IdentiferFormat=""/> 
</PersonIdentifiers>
```

What I want in the response is just 1 or the first  "IDNumber" of the row where IDType=WEB
I am currently using below xquery which has for loop to go through the array and return me value if IDType=WEB. But Ia m not bale to stop after the first successful value.
How can i achieve that?

My current xquery:

```
        <ns2:account>

        <acc:persons>
            <acc:person>
                <acc:personID>{fn:data($PersonMaintenanceResponse/ns1:PersonIdentifiers/ns1:PIR/@IDType)}</acc:personID>
                {
                for $PIR at $position in $PersonMaintenanceResponse//ns1:PersonIdentifiers/ns1:PIR
                return
                if($PersonMaintenanceResponse//ns1:PersonIdentifiers/ns1:PIR[$position]/@IDType='WEB')
                then
                    if ($PersonMaintenanceResponse/ns1:PersonIdentifiers/ns1:PIR[$position]/@IDNumber)
                    then <acc:ID>{fn:data($PersonMaintenanceResponse/ns1:PersonIdentifiers/ns1:PIR[$position]/@IDNumber)}</acc:ID>
                    else ()
                else
                ()
                }

            </acc:person>
        </acc:persons>
    </ns2:account>
```

Response from my xquery

```
  <ns2:account>
<acc:persons xmlns:acc="***************">
  <acc:person>

    <acc:ID>abc</acc:ID>
    <acc:ID>aaaaaa</acc:ID>
    <acc:ID>aaaaaa</acc:ID>

  </acc:person>
</acc:persons>
```

Expected Response is, just to get the first ID , we do not need otehr ids, how can i stop after getting 1st id

```
  <ns2:account>
<acc:persons xmlns:acc="***************">
  <acc:person>
     <acc:ID>abc</acc:ID>
  </acc:person>
</acc:persons>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use predicates as filters,  and index position to get the first

```
for $n in PersonIdentifiers/PIR[@IDType ="WEB"][1]
return
   data($n/@IDNumber)
```

Returns `abc`

see:
http://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbUY4kr/1

or as XPATH 1-liner

```
<account>
  <persons>
    <person>
        <ID>{data(PersonIdentifiers/PIR[@IDType ="WEB"][1]/@IDNumber)}</ID>
    </person>
  </persons>
</account>
```